# Как отменить кэширование веб страниц? Самый простой способ

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5

Как отменить кэширование веб страниц? Самый простой способ.

Comment: Смотря где и для чего. Если для разработки - то в консоли браузера галочку "Disable cache" поставить

Comment: Нет, сайт уже разработан. Кэш не нужен из-за динамического обновления данных на странице.

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```